# How can I change CSV import image as replace?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

When I import products with CSV file with `base_image`,`small_image`,`thumbnail_image` and `additional_images` values it's adding images as new images.

I want to it replace with current images.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In the import section while importing the products,select Add/Update in the import Behavior.Hope it works let me if any issues

Comment: It's adding images as new not replacing..
When i select "Replace" it's genereting new id's that i don't want.